# Subtract month/year to get years

Tags: r, date

```
data = data.frame("start"= c("1/2000","8/2004","99/9999"),
                  "stop"=c("1/2001","2/2007","09/2010"),
                  "WANTYEARS"= c(1,2.5,NA))
```

I have date in month/year format and want to subtract to get the years.

My attempt of simple data$stop - data$start did not yield the desired results. THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `difftime` from base R. Add "01" to `stop` and `start` date to create an actual Date object and subtract those dates using `difftime` with unit as `"weeks"` and divide it by number of weeks in year to get time difference in year,

```
round(difftime(as.Date(paste0("01/", data$stop), "%d/%m/%Y"), 
      as.Date(paste0("01/", data$start), "%d/%m/%Y"), units = "weeks")/52.2857, 2)

#[1] 1.0 2.5  NA
```

We can do the same using any other unit component of `difftime` as well if we know the equivalent year conversion ratio like for example with `"days"`

```
round(difftime(as.Date(paste0("01/", data$stop), "%d/%m/%Y"), 
      as.Date(paste0("01/", data$start), "%d/%m/%Y"), units = "days")/365.25, 2)
#[1] 1.0 2.5  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

The `yearmon` class represents months and years as years and fraction of a year.
Using `data` shown in the Note at the end:

```
library(zoo)

transform(data, diff = as.yearmon(stop, "%m/%Y") - as.yearmon(start, "%m/%Y"))
```

giving:

```
    start    stop diff
1  1/2000  1/2001  1.0
2  8/2004  2/2007  2.5
3 99/9999 09/2010   NA
```

### Note

```
data = data.frame(start= c("1/2000", "8/2004", "99/9999"),
                  stop = c("1/2001", "2/2007", "09/2010"))
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility involving `dplyr` and `lubridate` could be:

```
data %>%
 mutate_at(vars(1:2), list(~ parse_date_time(., "my"))) %>%
 mutate(WANTYEARS =  round(time_length(stop - start, "years"), 1))

       start       stop WANTYEARS
1 2000-01-01 2001-01-01       1.0
2 2004-08-01 2007-02-01       2.5
3       <NA> 2010-09-01        NA
```